# What is a better way to say the phrase 腳都軟掉?

Tags: word-choice, usage

Popular in Japanese anime and cartoons, after someone says something "cringy", you often see people falling down and having their feet in the air. What would be a good way to describe this phenomenon, both in Chinese and English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest 「**翻倒**」and  that is "**flipped**" in English

Example:

「他此言一出，眾人**翻倒**」; "Once  he said that, everyone **flipped**"

Also, in this kind of scene, the audience was figuratively "being knocked out" or "**floored**". I found the idiom "blow someone away" be a good match, and from the example sentence, I found "knock someone off their feet" suit even better.

> http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blow+away
>
> Blow somebody away also blow away somebody:
>
> 1. To cause someone great pleasure or surprise knock somebody off their feet
>
> *"Everyone I tell that story to, I mean everyone, is just blown away."*
>
> Related vocabulary: blow your mind

Example:

"Once he said that. Everyone was **blown away**!"

"His stupid words **knock everybody off their feet**!"

"His stupid words **floored** everyone!"

As for Chinese slang, 「**雷倒**」http://baike.baidu.com/view/1816380.htm describe the reaction scene  very well.

Example:
「他的蠢話，**雷倒**眾人」

Answer (score 0):

'cringy' is nothing good. It implies dislike, disgust. 'cringe' basically means 'become bent' a kind of attempt to become a circle (kring)

Blown away, knocked off my feet are positive, you are impressed almost to disbelief.

‘floored‘ is probably from boxing or prize fighting, literally 'knocked to the floor', figuratively 'stopped， made silent'

linedict has several examples for cringe:

由于尴尬/ 恐惧而畏缩

http://ce.linedict.com/dict.html#/cnen/example?query=cringe

My trusty translator is still sleeping, but maybe someone can offer a more colloquial version of:

他们由于尴尬脚在空中地倒下了。  (Trusty translator does not like this)
They collapsed with embarrassment, their feet sticking up in the air.

Trusty translator arose, suggested:

仰面倒地四脚朝天。 (Although maybe not 4 legged)

（They) fell flat on their backs, legs skyward.